# Problemas com função que retornar vetor de caracteres em C++

Tags: c++, string, ponteiro

Segue o código:

```
#include <iostream>

char* criaVetor(){

     char vetor[20]="Olá mundo!";
     return vetor;
}

int main(){

    char retorno[20]=criaVetor;

    std::cout << retorno;

    return 0;
}
```

> error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer

Não entendi muito bem, o que eu tenho que fazer para contornar esse erro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leonardo, parece que em boa parte você está confundindo coisas de uma linguagem com outra. Vou explicar para você os erros que achei.

```
char retorno[20] = criaVetor ;
```

Primeiro, chamada de função tem parênteses, sempre, mesmo sem argumentos.

```
char retorno[20] = criaVetor() ;
```

Segundo, para inicializar um vetor de chars citando os valores dos elementos deve-se usar `"Olá mundo!"` ou `{'O','l','á',' ','m','u','n,'d','o','!','\0'}`. Nenhuma função pode retornar isso.

No caso, a função retorna um ponteiro para char, portanto com ele só se pode inicializar um ponteiro para char, não vinte elementos de array. O `retorno` é tratado como um ponteiro constante, logo não pode ser atribuído ou inicializado.

```
char *retorno = criaVetor() ;
```

Se quer que no final das contas um array de vinte elementos tenha o valor das células no ponteiro retornado, você terá que copiar esses valores um por um. Para isso, você pode usar a função `std::string::copy` da biblioteca string (`#include <string>`).

Terceiro, na função você retorna o ponteiro que aponta para células que só existem durante a execução da função (alocados localmente na pilha de execução). Ao finalda função, as células naquele ponteiro não mais existem, o que dá risco de bug.

```
char* criaVetor(){
     char vetor[20] = "Olá mundo!";
     return vetor;
}
```

Tem três soluções e acho que no caso a mais rápida é dar um tempo de vida prolongado às células dessa função usando palavra-chave `static`. Com a palavra-chave `static` numa variável local, ela passa a ter o mesmo tempo de vida do programa, ou seja, ela vai existir mesmo depois de terminar de executar a função e na próxima chamada vai ter o mesmo valor que tinha na última vez.

```
char* criaVetor(){
     static char vetor[20] = "Olá mundo!";
     return vetor ;
}
```

Outro jeito é você alocar o array de 20 elementos usando palavra-chave `new`, depois atribuir os valores das células com a string (para isso pode copiar usando a função `std::string::copy` citada lá em cima) e retorna. Mas o problema é que você terá que controlar a existência dela, usando `delete` quando não precisar mais dela.

Tem mais uma opção (acho mais adequada), que é o "não uso de ponteiros para char" mas sim da classe string (está na biblioteca string, que citei a pouco), que aí ela controla todas essas questões envolvendo ponteiros, alocações, etc. Ponteiros para char é mais coisa de linguagem C do que C++, já classe string é de C++ e existe exatamente para para facilitar sua vida. Use ponteiros somente se necessário.

Alguma dúvida?

Comment: Essa parte de eu não colocar os parenteses foi erro na hora de postar o código, mas de resto...obrigado por responder :)

Comment: Beleza. Esquisito... dei a resposta mais completa, mais clara e tudo mais, até foi marcada como a solução e, mesmo assim, tem saldo final de 2 votos contra!

Comment: não liga mano...

Answer (score 3):

Tem alguns problemas neste código, o que está sendo mostrado é que está chamando o função sem os parênteses. Se chamar `criaVetor()` este erro desaparece.

Só que na verdade tem outro erro, você está criando um vetor local ([*stack*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101)) dentro desta função e retornando ele, o problema é que no momento que termina a função esse vetor é destruído então você está retornando algo que não poderá ser acessado.

Uma solução possível é alocar no *heap*, aí o conteúdo não é destruído. Embora isto não seja o ideal, o mais correto é alocar a memória onde será usada e passar um ponteiro desta alocação, que geralmente pode ser local mesmo e aí a função usa este local de armazenamento, assim você controla melhor o tempo de vida e corre menos riscos de ter vazamento de memória. Em C costuma-se usar `malloc()`, em C++ costuma-se usar o operador `new`.

Mas há outro problema, está usando C++ e tentando usar um vetor de caracteres. Isto não é o recomendado, use uma [`string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) e esqueça todas essas dificuldades. Ou seja, em C++ programe em C++, não em C. Algo assim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string criaString() {
    return "Olá mundo!";
}

int main(){
    string retorno = criaString(); //esta variável nem é necessária
    std::cout << retorno;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/xZQlU6). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/wytgtnyt-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/String/Return.cpp).